# Conductance measurement of InAs/GaSb Quantum Spin Hall Edges

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, measurements, topological-insulators

My questions are related to recent article:
http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1507/1507.08362.pdf

I can't figure out how their sample (wafers) actually looked like.
In particular I can't understand where they put contacts and where they are on the Fig. 2 in the article.
In my understanding contacts should be right on the edges, but from what article says it seems like contacts are made from indium and are right on the top of the wafers.
I drew a picture of six-terminal Hall bar device :
[image: 1]

So is that true that

- in their measurements the whole sample is "made of wafer" (even these terminals on the picture)?
- contacts actually "touch" the edge of InAs/GaSb interface? Or are they on the top of wafers?

Also tunneling conductance is discussed in the article. So I have another question. Through what do electrons actually tunnel in this experiments?

Finally, on the figure 3 in the article there is an image of the wafer B device. Where is the edge of the InAs/GaSb interface on this image?

I'm quite ignorant in the topic, so any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Contacts are on top, since the 2D gas is deep inside a complicated multilayer structure designed to generate a pure 2D gas as a quantum well. See picture on the web about 2D gas made for quantum Hall device. The article you cite is beyond paywall. Could you give a free-to-read link please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FraSchelle, thank you for reply, link to arxiv: http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1507/1507.08362.pdf

Comment: But if contacts are on the top, wouldn't it lead to other sources of resistance in the system? Is it this resistance they substracted from all their data measurements. Is it a tunneling resistance (as far as i understand it's not the same tunneling resistance, they discuss further)?

Comment: I believe all your answers are in the paper. Fig.2 is a clear picture of the multilayer system for instance. They discuss the contact resistance in a section somewhere at the end. I do not have time to extract these data for you, sorry.